# HTML manipulation: Match the first X number of HTML tags and move them

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, html-parsing

Let's say I've have the code like this:

```
<img src="001">
<img src="002">

<p>Some content here.</p>

<img src="003">
```

What I want to do now is to match the first two images (001 and 002) and store that part of the code in variable. I don't want to do anything with third image.

Id used something like `preg_match_all('/<img .*>/', $result);` but it obviously matched all the images. Not just those which appear on the top of the code. How to modify that regular expression to select just images that are on top of the code.

What I want to do is to now. I've have `<h2>` tag with title in one variable and the code above in the second. I want to move the first X images before the `<h2>` tag *OR* insert that `<h2>` tag after first X images. All that in back-end PHP. Would be fun to make it with CSS, but flexbox is not yet here.

Comment: What qualifies the top of the code? Everything before the first empty line?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with Regex.

Comment: Use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: "I want to parse HTML with regex" => too localised (why would anybody do that?)

Comment: Why do you need to shuffle elements around with PHP?

Comment: @hakre Well... basically yes. I didn't thought of that. But it isn't _everything_ before the first empty line, but every image before the first empty line.

RohitJain moonwave99 JanDvorak I am not a PHP programmer and I know only the basics. Found DOMDocument lacks needed selectors to do what I want, maybe I'm wrong.

Blender There is no good way to horizontally shuffle elements in CSS yet.

Comment: When you use DOM (not XPath) you can traverse the <img> parent node until the <p> is reached.

Comment: @hek2mgl: That's a good idea, too. And acutally this would work very good with xpath, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to divide the problem to solve it. You have got two main parts here:

1. Division of the HTML into Top and Bottom parts.
2. Doing the DOMDocument manipulation on (both?) HTML strings.

Let's just do that:

The first part is actually quite simple. Let's say all line separators are `"\n"` and the empty line is actually an empty line `"\n\n"`. Then this is a simple string operation:

```
list($top, $bottom) = explode("\n\n", $html, 2);
```

This solves the first part already. Top html is in `$top` and the rest we actually do not need to care much about is stored into `$bottom`.

Let's go on with the second part.

With simple `DOMDocument` operations you can now for example get a list of all images:

```
$topDoc = new DOMDocument();
$topDoc->loadHTML($top);
$topImages = $topDoc->getElementsByTagname('img');
```

The only thing you need to do now is to remove each image from it's parent:

```
$image->parentNode->removeChild($image);
```

And then insert it before the `<h2>` element:

```
$anchor = $topDoc->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0);
$anchor->parentNode->insertBefore($image, $anchor);
```

And you're fine. Full code example:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<h2>Title here</h2>
<img src="001">
<p>Some content here. (for testing purposes)</p>
<img src="002">

<h2>Second Title here (for testing purposes)</h2>
<p>Some content here.</p>

<img src="003">
HTML;

list($top, $bottom) = explode("\n\n", $html, 2);

$topDoc = new DOMDocument();
$topDoc->loadHTML($top);
$topImages = $topDoc->getElementsByTagname('img');
$anchor = $topDoc->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0);
foreach($topImages as $image) {
    $image->parentNode->removeChild($image);
    $anchor->parentNode->insertBefore($image, $anchor);
}

foreach($topDoc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $child)
    echo $topDoc->saveHTML($child);
echo $bottom;
```

Output:

```
<img src="001"><img src="002"><h2>Title here</h2>
<p>Some content here. (for testing purposes)</p>
<h2>Second Title here (for testing purposes)</h2>
<p>Some content here.</p>

<img src="003">
```

Comment: `explode("\n\n", $html, 2)` seems brittle.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: If the (written) preconditions are met, then not. Would alternatively `preg_split("\R\s*\R", $html, 2)` look less brittle to you?

Comment: This looks perfect, but the one thing that can happen is when there is no images on the top. Or it would just do nothing, because it wouldn't find any `<img>` tags?

Comment: Well it would move zero images - which results in something that could be described as "doing nothing", yes ;)

Comment: @hakre Thank you very much for that and that you straighten everything for me.

Comment: @hakre, No.  Creating a DOMDocument from the entire input and then pulling the first x images out would seem less brittle.  Maintainers are much less likely to be surprised when changes to tag structure break code assumptions than when changes to ignorable white-space break code assumptions.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Do you know how to find the first empty line in a HTML fragment you pull into a DOMDocument via `DOMDocument::loadHTML()`?

Comment: @hakre, I don't have to because I wouldn't write code that depends on the HTML having empty lines in it in the first place.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Well, then what I suggest is less brittle because it separates that problem away. ;)

Comment: @hakre, This solution is brittle because it makes assumptions about "ignorable white-space" which maintainers often assume they can ignore too.  You can make it less brittle by just doing literally what the question asks : "returning the first X elements of a type."

Comment: @MikeSamuel: As X is a variant and unknown, it's value needs to be programmatically found first. As condition for that, X is the number of images before the first empty line. That is what the code does. If you have got a better idea, feel free to share, however you can not let X stand variable but must give it a value. How would you do? And no need to downvote. I wouldn't do with empty lines either, however OP confirmed above that this is what it is.

Comment: Guys, the truth is that is should be handled by CSS and that's it. But for that I would need new box model to work on all browsers and that is not possible for now, so this is just a quick fix for a problem that will he handled in a much better way in the future (Firefox 20 as I recall would support new flexbox).